# Get user input from web form to save to text file

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a web form made that consists of checkboxes, radio buttons and a dateTimePicker.

All of the options work on the form, however I need to somehow get all user input e.g when someone checks 'checkBox1' to save to a text file. Im not sure how to do this in C#.

So far I have -

```
string path = "path";

        try
        {

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                File.Delete(path);
            }

            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
            {
                Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("");
                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
```

I can get the file to write out each specific checkbox name but I want to be able to write out only the checkboxes that have been checked.

I thought it would be something like - `if checkbox1.checkedstate = true`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify ur question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to immediately write file when check box is checked, set `AutoPostBack` to `true` and add `oncheckedchanged` event

**EDITED**

sample (with two checkboxes):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack=true OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack=true OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

in codebehind

```
    protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (chb.Checked)
        {
            //checkbox is checked
            //chb.ID gets the ID of the sender (i.e. checkbox1, checkbox2, etc)
            //write to file
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is good but is there a way of doing it without having to have a protected void for all checkboxes, radio buttons etc? Perhaps to read the file at the start of the programme and close it at the end with all selections written out?

Comment: @Jambo  as for the first question: yes there is a way. no need to hardcode `oncheckedchanged` event handler for all checkboxes. (I'll update answer). for the second question: can you elaborate it bit more?

Comment: sorry I have been rather vague I see, for instance once a usr has checked a specific checkbox, I need that check box name 'checkBox1' to write to a file. Butit has to be generic for all text boxes not just the first one. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

you want to check

```
if(checkbox1.Checked)
   write code
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question isn't much clear, I am assuming that you want to do something when you find the `CheckBox` `checked`, so you could do

```
if(myCheckBox.Checked) //Checked is a boolean 
/////// do something
```